Is "I remember typing in twenty-five years ago" proper English?
I'm reading a book called Outliers. One part describes a very successful software designer Bill Joy, who helped rewrite UNIX. He achieved such a good result that Apple apparently used it as a foundation to build IOS.

'If you put your Mac in that funny mode where you can see the code' Joy says' I see things that I remember typing in twenty-five years ago'

I've never heard anyone say that they were doing something in x years ago (usually it's x years ago). The only context this could apply for me would be the Back to the Future franchise. I know it applies to future evens e.g. I'll visit you in a year. Is this a correct/common usage?

You've parsed this wrong. The "in" does not relate to "twenty-five years ago", but to "typing", as part of the compound verb "type in", ie enter into a computer.

I see things that (I remember) (typing in) (twenty-five years ago).


Omg, ur totally right. Now it's so obvious. Thank you. #English hard language :)

If computers had been invented 100 years earlier, people would remember typing-in (with a hyphen), like British people used to call listening to the radio listening-in in the 1920s.

@MichaelHarvey those two are not quite the same ... typing in is inputing text into a computer
